# Apex Charts: how do I change tooltip position to be always on top?

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

By default Apex Charts tooltip positioning is calculated automatically: https://codepen.io/apexcharts/pen/xYqyYm. According to their docs, you can only change it to `fixed` and put in one of the corners:

```
Apex.tooltip = {
    fixed: {
      enabled: true
    }
  };
```

How do I change it to be always centered on top of the marker?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone wants to change the position of tooltips without creating a custom one (cause it poses new difficulties). I am 100% sure there is a better way to do this, but here is my solution:

```
Apex.chart = {
    events: {
        mouseMove: function(event, chartContext, config) {
            var tooltip = chartContext.el.querySelector('.apexcharts-tooltip');
            var pointsArray = config.globals.pointsArray;
            var seriesIndex = config.seriesIndex;
            var dataPointIndex = config.dataPointIndex === -1 ? 0 : config.dataPointIndex;

            if (seriesIndex !== -1) {
                var position = pointsArray[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex];

                tooltip.style.top = position[1] + 'px';
                tooltip.style.left = position[0] + 'px';
            }
        }
    }
};
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/oNgJajw

Source - Form GitHub post.

Comment: Oh yeah that was my post on Github haha. However it doesn't work well on touch devices.

Comment: New versions of apexcharts allow dataPointMouseEnter events, so that wojuld probably be more suitable, since tooltips only show up when u hover over it in some charts.

Comment: i am using line chart and the `pointsArray` is always an empty array